# How to "balance" twocolumn document with chessboard?

Tags: two-column, chess, chessboard

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chessboard}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[top=2cm,nofoot,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\lhead{Easy}
%\chead{}
\rhead{test}
%\rhead{SCHOOL NAME}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%% FONT
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona} %nice font

%% OWN command

\newcommand{\game}[3]{
    \item (#1 point) \\
    \chessboard[
    setfen= #2,
    mover= #3
    ]
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{enumerate}[Q1.]
\game{1}{1k/pb3p/3p3r/3p3p/1R2rP/2R4B/PP4P/6K}{W}
\game{1}{5b/1pp/6pp/1P1k1p/2KPp/4P/rn2Nppp/2R3K}{W}
\game{1}{/1p2rk/p1pK1n/P/1P/7Q}{B}
\game{1}{4k/p4p//R2pPKPp/3P3P/7r}{B}
\game{1}{r2qkbnr/1p3ppp/p1n/2P/2bpN//PPP1QPPP/R1B1K1NR}{W}
\game{1}{/1p3k/4p1p/Pp2P/1b2qp/1K2Q1p/3B}{W}

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Which produces this
[image]

I am typing a sheet of chess puzzles as shown above. 
How could I kind of "balance" the two columns, like this

[image]

Additionally,

```
\mainline{1. Rc8#}
```

does not seem to be working. I am tying to figure out a way to type the solution too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the point info and the board e.g. in a tabular so that they can't be separated. Also use \raggedbottom, so that the columns don't stretch:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chessboard}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[top=2cm,nofoot,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\lhead{Easy}
%\chead{}
\rhead{test}
%\rhead{SCHOOL NAME}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%% FONT
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona} %nice font

%% OWN command

\newcommand{\game}[3]{
    \item \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
     (#1 point) \\
    \chessboard[
    setfen= #2,
    mover= #3
    ]
    \end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}\raggedbottom
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{enumerate}[Q1.]
\game{1}{1k/pb3p/3p3r/3p3p/1R2rP/2R4B/PP4P/6K}{W}
\game{1}{5b/1pp/6pp/1P1k1p/2KPp/4P/rn2Nppp/2R3K}{W}
\game{1}{/1p2rk/p1pK1n/P/1P/7Q}{B}
\game{1}{4k/p4p//R2pPKPp/3P3P/7r}{B}
\game{1}{r2qkbnr/1p3ppp/p1n/2P/2bpN//PPP1QPPP/R1B1K1NR}{W}
\game{1}{/1p3k/4p1p/Pp2P/1b2qp/1K2Q1p/3B}{W}

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Never knew about `\raggedbottom`. What a surprise to see the author replying to my post!! Is there a way to use `mainline{}` for tying the answers? I can't seem to get it work and have to use it with `\newgame` ?

Comment: Mainline is not the right command. Check the xskak docu for alternatives or ask a new question.

Comment: Yes I know I have to use the `xskak` package. But I thought `mainline{}` is the command to write a move because it looks like exactly what I want. Thanks. I will print out the whole thing and have a detailed look.

Comment: \mainline tries to "play" the move. So it needs the correct start position. For simple printing of single moves this is normally overkill.

Comment: If one had more than 6 diagrams, e.g. 15, would one need to have an enumerate section for each 6 games, or would this setup just magically work for multiple pages? (Unable to try/run this example due to some fonts issue...)