# How to type a specific chess move?

Tags: chess

I am hoping to type a specific chess move, `Rc8` for example. But I have spent two hours searching and looking through existing packages like `chessboard`, `texmate`, `xskak` and `xskak`. I just couldn't find one.

They all seem to be "play" the moves.

Is there a way to just type `Rc8` as a move?
I am doing this like a solution for puzzles as [in here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458027/how-to-balance-twocolumn-document-with-chessboard/458028?noredirect=1#comment1152091_458028).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak} % 
\begin{document}
\wmove{Ra8} \variation{1. Ra8}

\bmove{Rxa8} \variation{1... Rxa8}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to type write using the BLACK rock for ''\bmove{Rxa8}'', as now both symbols are the same and look like no real different for black and white pieces. What syntex produces the actual pieces for King Queen Rock Bishop Knight and Pawns but in both black and white symbols? Manuals don't really say that ...

Comment: @CasperYC don't use comments for such a question, that is asking for personal support. Ask a new question.